# I do not understand error E0508

Tags: rust

When I tried to compile this code, I get the E0508 error:

> cannot move out of type `[Enum; 2]`, a non-copy fixed-size array

```
enum Enum {
    Val1 = 0,
    Val2 = 1,
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Enum::Val1, Enum::Val2];
    let x: i32 = a[0] as i32 + a[1] as i32;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

I just want to access a single value from an array of enum type.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a good idea to explain it, please.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but longer-term users rarely explain downvotes because they've experienced angry OPs going and down-voting in retaliation. I think most people downvote XOR comment.

Comment: are you sure it is `(grid[i][0]) + grid[i][1] + grid[i][2] / 3`, not `(grid[i][0] + grid[i][1] + grid[i][2]) / 3`?

Comment: Ok, that is sad, I will not learn from my mistakes...

Comment: @kennytm I do not know, that is another problem. I am currently trying to fix it.

Comment: As potential useful feedback, the question posed in your title isn't really great wording (I've been trying to come up with a better replacement and haven't found one). Your code is bigger than it needs to be, it's not a [MCVE]. Your link to the playground was also originally broken. These things combine to give the impression that you didn't put a large amount of effort into the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you. Can I copy/paste your minimal code in my question?

Comment: If you'd like, and if you think that it still properly captures the intent of your question. You may want to expand it a bit to use two enum values in the array and add together the integral values and print out the result to show how you'd like to use the code. One problem with an MCVE can be that it's *too* small, and you then get an answer that isn't useful in your real case. Asking good questions is tough!

Comment: I'm not sure the linked issue is actually related.

Comment: @KyleStrand hm I read too fast, I think you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A smaller reproduction:

```
enum Enum {
    Val1 = 0,
    Val2 = 1,
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Enum::Val1];
    a[0] as i32;
}
```

The easiest fix is to make your enum `Copy`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Enum {
    Val1 = 0,
    Val2 = 1,
}
```

> where is the copy needed?

This is a good question, and I'm not completely sure why the value needs to be moved when being coerced to an integer. It's nothing specific to do with arrays though:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Enum {
    Val1 = 0,
    Val2 = 1,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Enum::Val1;
    let b = a as i32;
    println!("{:?}", a); // Error: a was moved in the line above
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the minimalist reproduction, I tried to do this, but there were still too many lines :p And your solution works. Is it just possible to pass the grid as a reference, without making a copy of it ?

Comment: @Boiethios *possible to pass the grid as a reference* — you are already doing that: `&Grid`

Comment: I do not understand where the copy is needed?

Comment: Ok. So, when casting a value, the compiler try to move it somehow. In this example, I firstly thought it attempted to create a new (temporary) variable of type `i32`. But no: it wants to move the variable, and then reinterpret it. Strange.

Comment: @Boiethios Right; note that it's the *enum* that's being copied or moved, not the array, so either copying or moving is absolutely the right behavior (and cannot be optimized using references, since int32 is probably smaller than a pointer). And yes, I believe Rust makes all types movable by default and prefers moves to copies by default, which I believe makes sense (C++ gets into weird problems with its "copy-happiness"; e.g. std::function must always be copyable, which means it can't ever capture a unique pointer).

Comment: @KyleStrand Thank you for explanation. This answer deserves a question of its own.

Comment: @KyleStrand the part that I'm missing is that coercing an enum to a number *shouldn't* really involve a move of the enum. The new value is completely disjoint from the original one, so it shouldn't need to consume anything. I'd guess it's more of an edge case that people don't run into because why *wouldn't* you mark such a small enum as `Copy`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Not having used Rust nearly as much as I'd like to, I don't know if it automatically marks *any* user-defined types as `Copy`. If it does, I'm not sure why it wouldn't mark enums containing only primitive types as such.

Comment: @KyleStrand oh, no it definitely won't make anything `Copy` by default. My point is that getting the enum variant's discriminant shouldn't require consuming the value.

Comment: @Shepmaster My intuition has not failed me: ["The Copy trait is "opt-in" for user-declared structs and enums."](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md#controlling-copy-vs-move-with-the-copy-trait)

Comment: @Shepmaster What is the "discriminant"?

Comment: @KyleStrand I'm abusing the term a bit. [The `discriminant_value` function](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.discriminant_value.html) returns a number that represents the enum variant. It's probably not the right word, but I'm using it for the value that is assigning to an enum variant (a *C-like enum*).

Comment: @Shepmaster Probably the issue is that the `let` assignment takes the enum itself on the right-hand side, rather than using `discriminant_value` or some other way of extracting/copyig just the value.